# How to connect PhpStorm with Xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I hope somebody here can help me with my issue:

I recently gotten into my first PHP project and need to set up debugging. I'm aware many people had the same problem before me but I struggle to find a solution.

I need to set up PhpStorm with Xdebug and with all settings made its still not working and when I start my debug session i get stuck at this with no further information:

[image]

This is my project setup:

Docker Webapp with Xdebug: 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp

PhpStorm PHP Debug Settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Xdebug settings from `phpinfo()`:

[image]

Listening to debug connections in PhpStorm is on, starting a debug session create a session via GET: `https://localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=16957` but all my breakpoints are ignored.

Trying to get more information I ran `netstat`:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Enable xdebug log and share one for such unsuccessful debug session: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use run/debug configurations for web debugging, it's counter-productive. You can initiate debugging connections from the browser directly using [zero-configuration debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html).
2. Disable `xdebug.remote_connect_back`, it brings more harm than profit, especially with Docker.
3. `xdebug.remote_host` is not supposed to be `localhost` when you are using Docker, this way, the container is trying to send the debug data to itself instead of the host machine. It seems that you are using macOS and Docker for Mac, the correct hostname would be `host.docker.internal` in such a case.
4. If after you initiate a debugging session from the browser PhpStorm still cannot catch a connection, we'll need to take a look at the Xdebug log as @LazyOne suggested.

A blog post showing Docker in PhpStorm basics: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/

Answer (score 0):

i used this setting and it worked :)

```
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

with launch.json in vscode

```
 "name": "Listen 9000",
 "type": "php",
 "request": "launch",
 "log": true,
 "externalConsole": false,
 "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "/Users/folder/project/src"
     },
  "port": 9000,
```

With docker-compose.yml:

[image]