# Xdebug - trigger debug in PhpStorm from inside a docker

Tags: php, docker, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have been able to get my PHP scripts to trigger my listener in PhpStorm when opening a page from the browser. I just had to install Xdebug in the docker, and configure it with

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = Off
```

Now I wish to trigger it when calling a script from the PHP CLI inside the docker. I tried a few options like `php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=1 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=1 -dxdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 myscript.php` but without success. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62214236/783119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to @LazyOne comment I got the answer. From inside the docker, the script doesn't know to what host debug session should be sent. I simply needed to find my PC ip from the docker's POV, and use it as host.

Found it with `ip addr` and looked for `docker0` entry, and then used it as host:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"

php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=1 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=1 -dxdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.4 myscript.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Dockerfile` needs to have `EXPOSE 9000` (opens port `:9000`)

... else you won't be able to connect `xdebug` from the outside world.

Putting the IDE into the container is questionable.

Comment: Why? It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around...

Comment: It works in both ways... beside the local firewall may able prevent `:9000`.

Comment: If Docker uses TCP 9000 port for incoming connections .. then IDE will not be able to listen on that port...

Comment: The IDE should not be put into the container - so it has to connect from the outside. There might be cases where this might be useful, but ordinary it just bloats the container image. And actually it is `xdebug` which is listening on `:9000` (at least while it is running, else not).

Comment: *"And actually it is xdebug which is listening on :9000 (at least while it is running, else not)"* Please check Xdebug docs before making such statements, especially the "Communication Set-up" section: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication

Comment: Guys as I said the IDE gets Xdebug connections from the browser already even  though it calls a script inside the docker. It simply doesn't work from cli inside the docker